# Facebook shared link gives 'The page you requested was not found' in IOS native app

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-apps

I have a Facebook canvas app that creates wall posts on a community Facebook page.
At the same time, the app 'shares' a link to the new post on the users wall.

In all the browsers, clicking on the shared link takes you to a FB page with the original post.

In the native iOS FB App, clicking on the shared link gets a 'The page you requested was not found' error.

The shared link is of the form:  http://www.facebook.com/[ParentPageID] _ [PostID]

Facebook converts the link to the following form: http://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=[PostID]&id=[ParentPageID]

Any ideas?

Comment: I have had the same issues with my Android APplication, it has something to do with the setting page on the Facebook Dashboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complete answer:

To fix the problem I created a page within the app (PostingRedirectHandler.aspx) that serves as the focal point for all 'shared' links posted to user walls. Example:

https://fb.shoutoutforhope.org/PostingRedirectHandler.aspx?postID=370911822944882_152681898208096

This redirection works (so far) on all tested platform/browser combinations.

this is the code from the redirect:

```
string qString = Request.QueryString["postid"];
string[] fbPostData = qString.Split('_');
redirectLocation = "http://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=" + fbPostData[1].ToString() + "&id=" + fbPostData[0].ToString();
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information.  The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: curious as to why you would delete this?

Comment: ...because it looked like more information for the question, rather than an answer. If it's answer, it should say so. Since your edit, it does, so this is fine.

Answer (score 0):

that only happens if your `HASH KEY` generated from your application doesn't actually match the one you have entered on the `Facebook App Developer Page`

Comment: That may be another cause, but not the problem I was experiencing.  The FB App for iOS and Android still has problems with links of the form noted in my original post.

To fix the problem I created a page within the app (PostingRedirectHandler.aspx) that serves as the focal point for all 'shared' links posted to user walls.  Example:

https://fb.shoutoutforhope.org/PostingRedirectHandler.aspx?postID=370911822944882_152681898208096

This redirection works (so far) on all tested platform/browser combinations.